# Javascript array.push() special code

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hey guys i dont see the fault on my Code.

I just want to add some calculate numbers into my array.

Just look at the array named "numberOfarrays".
Why is the out-put look like that :

> 5050,2550,25,2050,25,20,1450,25,20...

and not like i thought:

> 50,25,20,14....

I am realy confused.

My Code:

```
<script>
    var a = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20];
    var sum= 0;//110
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
        sum = sum+a[i]
    }
    alert(sum);
    var tmp = 100/sum;//0,909..
    alert(tmp);
    var arryPlaetze = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {// 10 durchläufe
        arryPlaetze.push(Math.round(tmp*a[i])); 
    }
    var wheel =[];
    var lengthWheel = 100;
    var numberOfarrays =[];
    alert("numberOfarrays"+ numberOfarrays.toString());
    alert(arryPlaetze[1]);

    //Problem
    for (var i = 0; i < arryPlaetze.length; i++) {
        alert("zahler: "+i);
        alert("test "+Math.round(lengthWheel/arryPlaetze[i]));//50
        var tmp = Math.round(lengthWheel/arryPlaetze[i]);
        numberOfarrays.push(tmp);// fail why 5050 not 50,25


        document.write(numberOfarrays.toString());

    }

</script>
```

You can put the Code into a html to run it very easy.

Comment: Move `document.write(numberOfarrays.toString());` outside of the loop. You're showing the contents of the array at every step. It'd be even better if you [used your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for logging information.

Comment: thx very much. now i found my fault. Sometimes you need to writte to poeple to get a solution ^^ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move your `document.write()` outside of your loop. Right now it is printing the array every time, which results in

```
(50)(50,25)(50,25,20)(50,25,20,14)
```

But since there are no `()`s, then it just prints as

```
505025502520...
```

Also as Mike C said it would be better for logging if you used `console.log()` instead of `document.write()`.

Comment: It would also be more effective for logging than "alerting."